Ubuntu 22.04 Apache2 CORS issue, headers not set after enabling headers and editing the Virtual Host file
I'm having problems getting headers to work to allow access to files on my server from another domain. Specifically CodePen.
I've enabled headers a2enmod headers and get headers_module (shared) when using the command apache2ctl -M | grep headers.
My Virtual Host is
<Directory /var/www/niksgames.com/public_html>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, HEAD"
</Directory>

The requested resource does not have the headers.
Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong.
